# Qt C++ Parentheses Matching & Highlight-Current-Line Functionality Not Working Together

Tags: c++, qt

Line count + highlighted line [CodeEditor] 
    * Tutorial [links to code at bottom]: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html

Parentheses matching 
    * Tutorial: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/QtQuarterly31.pdf - "Qt Quarterly: Issue 31 · Q3 2009" 
    * Code[downloadbale ZIP file]: "Issue 31 · Q3 2009: Matching Parentheses with QSyntaxHighlighter · Example Code" via https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/index.html

Issue: I cannot get "highlighted [current] line" and "parentheses matching" to work together 
    * In my project: 
        If I only have one of the following slots connected then the respective functionality will occur as desired, but I would like both functionalities 
        [Code appears inside "codeeditor.cpp"]
`connect(this, SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged()), this, SLOT(highlightCurrentLine()));`

`connect(this, SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged()), this, SLOT(matchParentheses()));` // shares same signal as the highlightCurrentLine slot

Extra details: 
        * Qt Widget application using MinGW compiler 
        * Potential bug - Matching Parentheses [Have not done anything regarding this]: 
            * https://forum.qt.io/topic/13769/bug-in-qt-quarterly-31-matching-parentheses-with-qsyntaxhighlighter

**I am trying to make a code-editor using Qt based on tutorials, but I have basically copied and pasted the code from the tutorials into my project and still cannot get both the "highlighted current line" and "parentheses matching" to work together. **

Because there is a lot of code I have included each file's code in a Hastebin.

codeeditor.h: 
https://hastebin.com/ogetimapux.cpp

codeeditor.cpp: 
https://hastebin.com/ojagazoboq.cpp

highlighter.h: 
https://hastebin.com/amiribaquc.cpp

highlighter.cpp: 
https://hastebin.com/isawefequk.cpp

main.cpp: 
https://hastebin.com/adelucurak.m

**Update 1** 
Using the new "connect" syntax did not work. Nor did calling both these functions in the same slot.

```
    setExtraSelections(extraSelections);
```

When I comment out that line which appears various times in the code; in the "highlightCurrentLine" method, the parentheses matching will work but off course this disabled the highlighting of the current line which is not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the exact cause would be as you should be able to connect a single signal to multiple slots. You can always just create another function that calls highlightCurrentLine() and matchParentheses() and connect the signal to that slot instead.

Also the connect() syntax is much nicer these days as you can instead just do:
`connect(this, &QPlainTextEdit::cursorPositionChanged,this,&CodeEditor:someFunction)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a bug with Qt itself, regarding "  setExtraSelections(extraSelections);", reason why is that I un-installed and re-installed Qt Creator and ran the same project which works exactly as expected, which makes sense because I was using a slightly [about a month old] out of date Qt Creator.

Answer (score 0):

Although the author of this question seems to be inactive two years ago, I still want to share here because it took me a long time to solve it.

The issue is in the `CodeEditor::highlightCurrentLine` function. You need to get the previous extraSelections instead of creating a new one.

```
void CodeEditor::highlightCurrentLine()
{
    // Change this line
    QList<QTextEdit::ExtraSelection> extraSelections;
    // To this line (you should rename the extraSelections variable:
    QList<QTextEdit::ExtraSelection> extraSelections = QPlainTextEdit::extraSelections();

    if (!isReadOnly()) {
        QTextEdit::ExtraSelection selection;

        QColor lineColor = QColor(Qt::yellow).lighter(160);

        selection.format.setBackground(lineColor);
        selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat::FullWidthSelection, true);
        selection.cursor = textCursor();
        selection.cursor.clearSelection();
        extraSelections.append(selection);
    }

    setExtraSelections(extraSelections);
}
```

However, if you only do this, the extra selections won't be cleared every time the cursor position is changed. You should make an `onCrsorPositionChanged` slot function, put all of your functions in it and insert this code in the first line:

```
    setExtraSelections({});
```